# Sticky header positioning

Tags: website-design, gui-design, interaction-design, web-app, layout

The page below is a detail page of a certain Patient, in this case: "Mevr adasfad..."

When end-users scroll down they'd like some additional feedback on what page exactly they are, the name of the patient that is.

In the screenshot you see when scrolled all the way to the top. You see the normal header with the name of the patient.
In the bottom part of the screenshot you see the header has disappeared (because of scrolling) so we added a black box with the name.

- Bottom left seems like a good fit, because it isnt in the way of the rest of the page.
- Top center seemed ok because that is where the original header was.

My question is, is this a good way of showing the name and if so where on the page should it be shown?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a logical way to display it, I'll go trough that 
[image]

And by the way, care about typo size if you go responsive, that's quite low here.

Comment: Could you eleborate why that would be the logical place? Simply because of the original positioning?

Comment: Sure. The first obvious thing is that for people who scroll down a page, informations (images, textes, etc..) go top. So their first thought is to imagine that those are above and hided. "first thought" is important. They can understand if you put it on the bottom left corner but it will take 2 sec instead of 1 and that's the point. In UX the only rule you have to remember is "Don't make me think" (copyrights S.Krug)

Comment: The bottom would also be good, in a similar fashion, as long as the div "fades in" -- otherwise it will be non-obvious where to look.  The top is the best choice, I think, because you don't know how tall the user's viewbox will necessarily be.  Bottom also works if you know that the monitor size will be limited.  Left-hand-side also might be good, but it's not possible to know if the user will resize the window and the text you want to show is wider than it is tall.  My recommendation is to collapse the existing header when a user scrolls down - to keep the placement and the colors consistent